# Error while executing Pylint command from terminal on Django Project directory

Tags: python-3.x, django, pylint

**When i run the below command from my terminal i end up getting the below error, i am running this pylint on my django-project.**

```
(venv) mypc:~/path/django-project$ pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc ./* > lint_ouput.txt

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 390, in find_cookie
    line_string = line.decode('utf-8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 9: invalid start byte

pylint.exceptions.InvalidMessageError: Message E0001 must provide line, got None
```

Comment: what do you want to mean by `./*`? if you want to run pylint on the entire folder use the folder name. if for a specific file use the file name (Relative path)

Comment: @Orb ./* points to the current directory and runs the pylint on all the folders and files containing .py files, I dont have any specific files or folder to run pylint on.

Comment: well this is what I get:
input terminal: pylint ./*
output:
************* Module ./*
./*:1:0: F0001: No module named ./* (fatal)

Comment: Command:  pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc <directory_name>, worked for me without any errors. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it clear for other users I sum up the solution:

The `./*` symbol is not needed. It looks like Pylint is unable to parse your command properly. if you want to run Pylint on the entire folder use the folder name. e.g:

`pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc <file1_name> <file2_name>`

if for a specific file use the file name (Relative path)

`pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc <dir_name>`